# Creating interactive drop down lists in a post

Tags: posts

I am writing a blog post and in that blog post i want to have a drop down list which contains all the football teams and upon selecting a specific team in that drop down box would lead to a change in second drop down list or box which would contain the players names. How could i do this in word press especially without the use of coding. Any pointers very much appreciated﻿. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately unless there's a plugin you can't do this custom code (javascript) on wordpress.com - [see "Javascript" section on this page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/).

You could do this on a self-hosted wordpress.org site using a plugin like this: [Ajax Dropdowns](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-dropdowns/)

You might be able to use a form builder and then iframe it in to your page like Wufoo: https://www.wufoo.com/guides/conditional-logic-and-branching/, but again this code can't have any javascript.